# How to define a macro with a functional character?

Tags: conditionals

I want to form a macro which will enable me to get the following result.

Let's say I want `L`, `M` & `N` to be active in my document.

And I also want character `p` to be functional in the code such that

- If `L` is followed by `p` it changes to `q`.
- If `M` is followed by `p` it changes to `r`.
- If `N` is followed by `p` it changes to `s`.

Can I define character `p` in this way?

---

The code provided by @Red-Cloud is great, but I have a different setup which I initially excluded from the MWE as not necessary, but now I find it necessary to be a part of it. This is the actual setup where I want to use this code.

There is one character 'x' which sets up a condition for the active characters. That condition says if an active character (L, M & N in our case) is ***not*** followed by 'x' then add X after them.

Code -

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\catcode`L=\active
\protected\def L{\bgroup a\futurelet\tmp\check}
\catcode`M=\active
\protected\def M{\bgroup b\futurelet\tmp\check}
\catcode`N=\active
\protected\def N{\bgroup c\futurelet\tmp\check}
\def\check{\ifx\tmp x\egroup\expandafter\@gobble\else X\egroup\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    LMN
\end{document}
```

This generates -

[image: 1]

Without changing this setup I want to add the previously asked settings (initial question) to it. In a way if I have `LpMpNp` in my input I want `qXrXsX` (look at condition set 1 and 2) Is it possible?

Comment: Shouldn't you stop asking again and again the same question? At least give a reference to the other similar ones.

Comment: @egreg I've not yet received any complete solution, I'm trying to reframe the question in a simpler way. I was asked to explain my question 'better'. I accepted my fault there and then tried to reframe it here. I purposely did not mention the references, because it might be more confusing for the reader. I'm sorry if I broke any rule of the site.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}    
\begin{document}    
\begingroup
\catcode`L=\active
\catcode`M=\active
\catcode`N=\active
\makeatletter
\def L{\@ifnextchar p{q\@gobble}{}}
\def M{\@ifnextchar p{r\@gobble}{}}
\def N{\@ifnextchar p{s\@gobble}{}}
\makeatother
Lp Lq Lr

Mp Mq Mr

Np Nq Nr    
\endgroup

Lp Lq Lr

Mp Mq Mr

Np Nq Nr    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: *Caveat*: this will gobble spaces directly following the main letter.

Comment: Thanks, This is working perfectly fine, but I've few more conditional settings which I excluded in my MWE. Unfortunately I don't know how to use the commands that you've recommended with my setup. Please check the edit.

Comment: `\def L{\@ifnextchar p{qX\@gobble}{}}`

Comment: This is probably a good hack, but what I want to achieve is having 'X' with the specific command **\def\check{\ifx\tmp x\egroup\expandafter\@gobble\else X\egroup\fi}** and replacements (LMN > qrs) by a different set of commands which you have provided. I don't want to code qX, rX and sX. Can you please suggest a command which will enable me to combine both of them? So that one set of commands will change L to q and the other command will see that x is absent and hence add 'X'.